# Connecting to PostgreSQL database from another machine using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, connection

I have a database with name `"Test"` in PostgreSQL 11 in my machine, I can connect to this database from my machine using QGIS with host localhost, but when I tried to connect it from a different machine with the same network by entering my IPv4 address it didn't work. So could you give me solutions pleas?

Comment: did you add the network to the postgres_hba file?

Comment: Because you have already set the configuration file, I suggest you establish the Transmission Control Protocol (TCP). Please follow this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4IhfbxhoAn8

Comment: Yes, I added other IPv4 addresses

Comment: what operating systems are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 10

Comment: is configured **Apache HTTP Server**?